# How is std::shared_ptr polymorphic?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, shared-ptr

I'm developing some container class, which has similar idea: holding pointer inside.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class Container
{
public:
    Container ( )
    {
         pointer = new T ( );
    }

    ~Container ( )
    {
        delete pointer;
    }

    T* operator->( )
    {
        return pointer;
    }
private:
     T* pointer;
};

struct Base
{
    virtual void who ( )
    {
        std::cout << "Base" << std::endl;
    }
};


struct Child : public Base
{
    virtual void who ( ) override
    {
        std::cout << "Child" << std::endl;
    }
};

void testContainer ( Container<Base> c )
{
    c->who ( );
}

void testSharedPtr ( std::shared_ptr<Base> s )
{
    s->who ( );
}

int main ( )
{
    Container<Child> child;
    std::shared_ptr<Child> sharedChild;

    testSharedPtr ( sharedChild );
    testContainer ( child );
}
```

This code fails to compile: **`error C2664: 'void test(Container<Base> &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'Container<Child>' to 'Container<Base> &'`**
However with `std::shared_ptr<Base>`, instead of `Container`, everything works fine. So question is:
Is *`std::shared_ptr`-like* polymorphysm implementable? Or is this feature, which was somehow hardcoded in C++? Sorry for my primitive language.

Comment: Have you looked at the interface of `std::shared_ptr`, particularly the [constructor overloads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)? That might answer your question. Also notice that your code would not compile even with `std::shared_ptr`, because the function takes a non-const reference. VS has an extension which allows it, but normally temporaries (such as those from the implicit conversion) cannot bind to non-const lvalue references.

Comment: Though, looking at answer below, it seems that your solution does not work in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the following constructor:

```
template<class Other,
         class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<Other*, T*>::value>::type>
Container(const Container<Other>& _Other) 
{
    pointer = _Other.pointer;
}
```

This constructor will only be enabled if `Other*` is convertible to `T*`, which is obviosly the case if `T` is the base class of `Other`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that will cause `delete` on the pointer to be called twice.

Comment: Jup, thats right. He has to implement another behavior.

Comment: Thank you, also there should be `friend class Container;`

Comment: Why that? The Constructor can access private members of other instances of the same template class without using a `friend`-declaration.

Comment: My MSVS2013 compiler does not agree with you. `error C2248: 'Container<Child>::pointer' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Container<Child>'`

Comment: I think, I can use some reference counting, yes?

Comment: Hmm weird... I don't need the friend with the very same compiler. Year, you need some sort of reference counting, unless you want to implement some kind of external garbage collector. But why don't you use std::shared_ptr? It has everything you want (including thread-safe reference counting).